# How to open a powerpoint presentation via python?

Tags: python, pyqt, powerpoint

Im struggling opening a powerpoint presentation via python.
I have a program in educational program in pyqt and i need to open up a powerpoint presentation(in powerpoint viewer mode) when i click a push button.

I tried using pywin32 and such but ive had no luck :(

Comment: In your button command (I don't know `pyqt` but I know how to open the file): `from os import startfile`; `startfile(_filepath_)`.

Comment: using `cmd`, just typing the filename into the prompt will open it using the default application for that filetype.  Maybe `subprocess.call` can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Import the `os` module, then use `os.system("powerpoint.exe filename")`